# Fibonacci class always returns 0

Tags: c#, math

I have this class:

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    public static int Calculate( int x )
    {
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return Calculate(x - 1) + Calculate(x - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Per a tutorial I'm doing if one inputs 6 one should get 8 as an expected result, but when I run it, it always returns 0.  It's recursive so it makes sense to me, but how do they get 8 as an expected result?

Comment: You should work that out by yourself, you will learn more. Hint: think what Calculate(0) does and what Calculate(1) does. And if you don't get it, use a debugger.

Comment: The Calculate method can't possibly be returning null - the return type is an integer, which cannot be null. I notice that in the text you say it returns zero - but in the title you say null. These are not the same thing - I suggest you update the title to say zero.

Comment: As a sidenote: recursion is not the best way to calculate fibonacci numbers. For instance when you use this way to calculate f(n), then f(n-2) is calculated twice. F(n-4) is calculated 5 times! Try it out on paper with f(6) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fibonacci sequence has 2 stopping points, and they're both 1 (1,1,2,3,5,...). This works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Fibonacci
{
    public static int Calculate( int x )
    {
        if (x <= 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return Calculate(x - 1) + Calculate(x - 2);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
     Console.WriteLine(Calculate(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's 0 based, so if you give it 5, it'll give back 8.

Answer (score 6):

What's 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + ... + 0?

There's your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You exit condition is wrong. Read through your code and think it through for inputs 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Either the tutorial is wrong or you copied the code incorrectly.  You are correct that it what you have above will always return 0.  Check your base cases.

Answer (score 0):

*Abductio ad absurdum* - Calculate(x) never actually returns a non-zero number. 8 is the sixth Fib number, but you're never creating a non-zero value from this function. As @Blindy points out, you need a more extensive and inclusive base case.